How do JavaScript instances access private methods without prototype inheritance?
My understanding is that private methods are not part of the prototype chain, and therefore, are not inherited by subclasses. However, I am confused about how instances of a class access private methods when those methods are invoked through public methods of the class.
class MyClass {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 'I am a private method';
  }

  publicMethod() {
    return this.#privateMethod(); // Access private method from within the class
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
console.log(instance.publicMethod()); // Logs: I am a private method

When instance.publicMethod() is called, this inside publicMethod refers to instance. Since private methods are not part of the instance itself or the prototype chain, how does this.#privateMethod() work? How does the private method get accessed even though the instance doesn't directly contain the private method?

Prototypes are to do with inheritance, which is not what's happening here. You've simply instantiated a new instance of the class, to which the private members are available

The private properties are part of the instance itself.

@Pointy - private fields get copied over to the instances but how are private methods part of the instance? (I'm comparing this to public methods which are not explicitly part of the instance but can be accessed via the inheritance chain).

"how are private methods part of the instance?" same way plain fields are added to the instance. It's not through the prototype - they are assigned at creation when invoking the constructor.

@VLAZ so each instance of the class will have a copy of the private methods (unlike public methods which are only accessed via prototype)?

Correct. They aren't part of the prototype, therefore are part of the instance. Therefore, they are added on each instance created. Same if you had class Foo { hello = "world" } and new Foo(); new Foo() will create hello for each instance.

@jimo there's not much of a difference between private fields and private methods; they're just private property names with values that are functions.

@Pointy - so building on to VLAZ's point - then do we say that private properties (fields, methods) both are copied over to instances unlike their public counterparts where public field is added but public method is only accessed via prototype?

That is accurate, yes. Note that you must reference private properties (fields or methods) via this.#name notation, and you can only do it from code in methods of the class. To me it's easier to think about it abstractly without worrying about exactly how things work internally.


The private methods are part of the instance
